# Deleting Windows performance counter categories

Tags: windows, performancecounter

I have a custom performance counter category. Visual Studio Server Explorer refuses to delete it, claiming it is 'not registered or a system category'. Short of doing it programmatically, how can I delete the category? Is there a registry key I can delete?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As far as I know, there **is no way** to safely delete them except programatically (they're intended for apps to create and remove during install) but it is trivial to do from a [PowerShell](http://Microsoft.com/PowerShell) command-line console. Just run this command:

```
[Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Delete( "Your Category Name" )
```

**HOWEVER: (EDIT)**

You *can* delete the registry key that's created, and that will make the category vanish.

For a category called "Inventory" you can delete the whole key at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Inventory` ... and although *I wouldn't be willing to bet that cleans up everything*, it **will** make the category disappear. (If you run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) while running the Delete() method, you can see can a lot of other activity happening, and there doesn't seem to be any other *changes* made).

It's important to note that **as I said originally**: when you get that error from Visual Studio, it might be that it's already deleted and you need to refresh the view in VS.  In my testing, I had to restart applications in order to get them to actually get a clean list of the available categories.

You can check the full list of categories from PowerShell to see if it's listed:

```
[Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::GetCategories() | Format-Table -auto
```

But if you check them, then delete the registry key ... they'll still show up, until you restart PowerShell (if you start another instance, you can run the same query over there, and it will NOT show the deleted item, but re-running GetCategories in the first one will continue showing it.

By the way, you can filter that list if you want to using -like for patterns, or -match for full regular expressions:

```
[Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::GetCategories() | Where {$_.CategoryName -like "*network*" } | Format-Table -auto
[Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::GetCategories() | Where {$_.CategoryName -match "^SQL.*Stat.*" } | Format-Table -auto
```

Answer (score 11):

You could also use LinqPad, as that doesn't involve an install of any kind - http://www.linqpad.net/.

Run the following code as a "C# Statement(s)":

`System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete("Name of category to delete");`

I'd run it twice, first time to do the actual delete, second time to get an error message to confirm the delete was successful.

Comment: Useful when the "sysadmins" you work with can't be bothered to install PowerShell on their own servers...

Comment: I found I had to run LINQPad as administrator for this to work otherwise I got a "not authorized" exception.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question if old but I found a way to do this non-programatically:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Use unlodctr from command prompt, you might also need to use lodctr /q to query your category.

Or do it the hard way by modifying the registry key (don't delete it):
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373172%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could disable it using the microsoft resource kit tool - install it from

http://download.microsoft.com/download/win2000platform/exctrlst/1.00.0.1/nt5/en-us/exctrlst_setup.exe

or disable it from the registry manually (have not tried) described here

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windows2000serv/reskit/regentry/94214.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I think this disables all counters for a specific service ... and doesn't help with getting rid of a "category"