# unregistering a performance counters

Tags: c#, performance, performancecounter

I have added performance custom counters to my application to
  whether the no of times the operation takes place or not .

But now I want to unregister it . 
  Is it possible to unregister it remove it .

I have used this counters in C#.

The class which creates a performance category and
  adds counters to it .

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GroupChatLibrarySamples
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Helper class to demonstrate the setup of performance counters.
    ///</summary>
    public class PerformanceCounterHelper
    {
        //Total number of tests executed
        private PerformanceCounter _TotalFiles = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public PerformanceCounterHelper()
        {
            // Set up the performance counter(s)
             if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists("Total_Files","."))
             {
                //Create the collection container
                CounterCreationDataCollection counters = new CounterCreationDataCollection();
                ////Create counter #1 and add it to the collection
                CounterCreationData tests = new CounterCreationData();
                tests.CounterName = "Total_Files_Sent";
                tests.CounterHelp = "Total number of Files Sent";
                tests.CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32;
                counters.Add(tests);

                //Create the category and all of the counters.
                PerformanceCounterCategory.Create("Total_Files", "Performance Counter for checking no of files sent", counters);
             }
             try
             {
                 _TotalFiles = new PerformanceCounter();
                 _TotalFiles.CategoryName = "Total_Files";
                 _TotalFiles.CounterName = "Total_Files_Sent";
                 _TotalFiles.MachineName = ".";
                 _TotalFiles.ReadOnly = false;
             }
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine(" {0} \n", e.StackTrace);

             }

        }


        public void IncrementCounters()
        {
            _TotalFiles.Increment();

        }
    }
}
```

The code where counter is incremented :

```
    private void BeginSendFilesFinished(IAsyncResult ar) 
    {

        currentOperation.End("BeginSendFilesFinished", () => session.EndUploadFile(ar)); 
        Console.WriteLine(" File Count  : {0} \n", listoffiles.Count);
        if(sentFiles <  (listoffiles.Count-1))
        {
                sentFiles++;  
                string SampleFile = listoffiles[sentFiles].ToString();
                FileInfo filetoupload = new FileInfo(SampleFile);                        
                ChatRoomFileUploadJob uploadfilejob = new ChatRoomFileUploadJob(filetoupload);
                counterHelper.IncrementCounters();   
                currentOperation.Begin(string.Format("Send Files: # {0}", sentFiles), () => session.BeginUploadFile(uploadfilejob, BeginSendFilesFinished, null));

        }
        else
        {
            Log("Leave ChatRoom:");
            // After sending 10 chat msgs, leave the chat room (and rejoin).
            currentOperation.Begin("Leave ChatRoom:", () => session.BeginLeave(BeginLeaveChatRoomFinished, null));
        }
    }
```

Thanks & Regards,
Tazim.

Comment: `Could you please provide us the code where you register it?`

Comment: I have added this counter, and monitoring it using perfmon .but I want to remove it know or delete it or unregister it . is it possible ? Any links and pointers will be valuable . Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to delete the counters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140149/deleting-windows-performance-counter-categories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be too obvious, but given that you're trying to do the opposite of the PerformanceCounterCategory.Create action (I think), have you looked at using [PerformanceCounterCategory.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecountercategory.delete.aspx)? According to the documentation it:

> Removes the category and its
>   associated counters from the local
>   computer